# WPF XAML - How to submit a parameter to a template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, commandparameter

I have a ContentControl with a Grid in it. There is a Template for ContextMenu of each ListBoxItem. The ContextMenu Looks like this:

```
<ContentControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="SimpleDataObjectContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Create" Command="{Binding AddRelation}" CommandParameter="..Name..of..caller.."/>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteRelation}" CommandParameter="..Name..of..caller.."//>
    </ContextMenu>
</ContentControl.Resources>
```

The Grid looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="LeftRectangle" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black" Margin="5" ContextMenu="{StaticResource SimpleDataObjectContextMenu}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Name}"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RightRectangle" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black" Margin="5" ContextMenu="{StaticResource SimpleDataObjectContextMenu}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to submit from the "LeftRectangle" and "RightRectangle" (which are using the own ContextMenu Template "SimpleDataObjectContextMenu") the x:Name to the "SimpleDataObjectContextMenu", so that I can submit this Name as CommandParameter in the Template.

Instead of ..Name..of..caller.. for example I want to send "LeftRectangle", if the ContextMenu was opened on the left rectangle...

Any idea, how can I realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DataContext` binding from your `ContextMenu`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="SimpleDataObjectContextMenu" >
    <MenuItem Header="Create" Command="{Binding AddRelation}" CommandParameter="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteRelation}" CommandParameter="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind command parameter like this

```
 CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Menu.UIElement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}
```

and in code behind you can cast the parameter with Rectangle like this

```
      var rectangle = parameter as Rectangle ;
      if(rectangle != null)
      {
       var name = rectangle.Name;
      }
```